# Probabilities under the log normal distribution, as well as mean and sd

Tags: probability, distributions

I have what are probably a pretty basic stats questions. I heard that under the log normal distribution, the mean =variance. Is this true? Or is this another distribution? I am having trouble finding this information online.

Second, if I have the mean and sd for a log normal distribution, how to I calculate the probability of a value under this distribution? I am assuming it can be transformed to the normal, but don't remember the steps to do this?

Comment: What does "==" mean?

Comment: Sorry, when using R and python, 'equals' often is expressed as "==" instead of '='. I did not realize I wrote that, I will edit.

Comment: The second question doesn't make sense - the probability of any value from a continuous distribution is 0. If you mean instead "how do I evaluate the density", that boils down to calculation of the parameters and substitution into the density. If you know the *population* mean $m$ and the *population* sd $s$ in a lognormal, the formulas are given in Wikipedia (in several places), such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Notation) (scroll down a bit to the $\mu=$ part), and also in numerous answers on site here. Once you have $\mu$ and $\sigma$ values, ... ctd

Comment: ... ctd just substitute whichever value you want the density at into the lognormal density (same wikipedia page, see the sidebar on the RHS near the top)

Answer (score 1):

"I heard that under the log normal distribution, the mean =variance. Is this true?" No. For normal distribution, mean and variance have no relation. For lognormal distribution, mean and variance have relation, but not determined each other.

"Or is this another distribution?" One of them is Poisson distribution.

"how to I calculate the probability of a value under this distribution?" The probability of a value for a continue distribution, such as lognormal, is zero. If you want the probability from a to b, use log(a) and log(b), then follows the way used to get the probability from normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I am kind of confused with the answer for the second part. I am not looking for  the probability under a range of values, just of one value. For example, if I have a mean of 4 and a sd of 2, and want to find the proability of getting a 3.5 under this distribution. Are you saying I should take a log of 4,2, and 3.5 and then calculate the probability like I would under the normal?

Comment: The probability of a value for a continue distribution, such as lognormal, is zero.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you are saying-the area under the curve for a single point is zero? Then when doing a t-test, how does one calculate the p since you are assuming a continuous distribution? Is it the distance from the value to the mean?

Comment: See graph here https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/statistical-concepts/hypothesis-testing/p-value-approach. Specifically, red area.

Comment: @Molls p-values are the probability of a result *at least as extreme* as the one observed, given the null hypothesis is true. That is, for continuous variates they relate to an area, not density at a point.